# How to do pagination using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having trouble in pagination in my datatable. I filter how many rows I can show in the table but pagination is not working. Here is my code:

```js
var table = '#accounttable'
$('#maxRows').on('change', function() {
  $('.pagination').html('')
  var trnum = 0
  var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val())
  var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length
  $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
    trnum++
    if (trnum > maxRows) {
      $(this).hide()
    }
    if (trnum <= maxRows) {
      $(this).show()
    }
  })
  if (totalRows > maxRows) {
    var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows)
    for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) {
      $('.pagination').append('<li  data-page="' + i + '"> \<span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\</li>').show()
    }
  }
  $('.pagination li:first-child').addclass('active')
  $('.pagination li').on('click', function() {
    var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page')
    var trIndex = 0;

    $('.pagination li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')

    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
      trIndex++
      if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
        $(this).hide()
      } else {
        $(this).show()
      }
    })
  })
})
```

[image]

Comment: I would cache the rows: `const $rows = $('#accounttable tr:gt(0)')`

Comment: Please consider editing your question and rewrite the code in a snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example